# How to make htdocs folder in opt/lampp writable?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, xampp, wordpress, htdocs

I have installed xampp on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. And when I run the server and try to upload images into wordpress page, it is showing an error.

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2021/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I have tried

```
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

by replacing username with my username. It is still throwing that error.

Comment: What is the username for the XAMPP installation?

Comment: The upload directory wp-content/uploads needs to be writable by the webserver running wordpress.

Comment: @user10489 which command to use ?